# Java binary search

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Binary_Search
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    for (int i = 5000; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int[] search = new int[1000];
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 5000 and 5999."));
            while (guess > 5999 || guess < 5000)
            {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 5000 and 5999."));  
            }

        int comparisons = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int max = search.length - 1;
        int avg = (min + max) / 2; 

        do 
        {
            if (guess > avg)
            {
              int temp = avg;
              avg = (guess + max) / 2;
              min = temp;
              comparisons ++;
            }
            if (guess < avg)
            {
              int temp = avg;
              avg = (guess + min) / 2;
              max = temp;
              comparisons ++;
            }
        } while (guess != avg);
        System.out.println("Your guess was " + guess + " and the number of comparisons was " + comparisons + ".");

    }
  }
}
```

This is a simple binary search program that I am working on, I know there are probably some problems with it but its a work in progress. 
I can't figure out why my code crashes at startup, could anyone tell me why?

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 5000; i < 1000; i++)
```

You are starting with i = 5000 - but then expect it to be less than 1000? The whole loop will never execute.

Comment: Wow, I am not a smart man.  Thank you.

Comment: @matthabitat this means it doesn't crash or even throw an error. It just doesn't run the loop which should be obvious if you step through your code in your debugger. BTW it's obvious to me because I have made this mistake myself. ;)

Comment: Has nothing to do with smart. Having trouble with the for syntax is quite common, don't worry.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, I will look at my code harder next time before asking on here.

Comment: There are some problems with the logic, yes. Seems to me that it's a little bit stuck. Personally, I would try it first with some easier values than 5000 - 5999, for example 1-10. If you got that, the rest is easy. I also don't understand what the array is for.